# use the definition of ($\epsilon, \delta$) proof to show asymptotically stable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, systems-of-equations

Compute the solution $\phi_t \overrightarrow x_0 = e^{At} \overrightarrow x_0$ to the system $x' = -x + 4y$ and $y' = -4x - y$.

i found the solution that
$$\phi_t (x,y) = e^{-t}\begin{bmatrix}\cos 4t & \sin 4t\\-\sin 4t & \cos 4t\end{bmatrix}*\begin{bmatrix}x_0\\y_0\end{bmatrix}$$

This is a spiral sink...so this is asymptotically stable. However, how do I use the definition of ($\epsilon, \delta$) proof to show it?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Look at the quantity $x^2 + y^2$ as a function of time.

---

Incidentally: a system itself is not "asymptotically stable". What is stable is a given **fixed point** of the system. In your case I am assuming you are talking about the fixed point $\vec{x}_0 = (0,0)$.